# Using the user's input path in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to bash and am trying to write a simple script.

The user executes my script and in the same line specifies the destination. In this destination, which I do not know in advance, I'd like to check if a **specific** hidden file exists and do something, and if not create the file.
The input looks as such:

```
./scriptName.sh /userPath
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking some simple command, and I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your example decide if the path to reach the supplied file will be

relative  ( some/child/dir/some_file )

or absolute ( /a/full/path/to/some_file )

... NOTICE the relative has no leading / whereas the absolute does

Then to determine whether that file exists just do

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit  # stop execution on error

given_file=$1 # retrieve input parameter and populate a variable

if [ -f given_file  ]; then
     echo do something here file does exist
else
    echo no file 
fi
```

After you have created your file scriptName.sh you need to turn on its execute bit by issuing

```
chmod +x scriptName.sh
```

do a file listing to show permissions before and then after issuing above then you are ready to execute it

```
scriptName.sh  /a/full/path/to/some_file
```

Comment: The input path will be absolute.  But still, how do I know what path is given?